# What does "breathe in romance of the past" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have read this sentence in the booklet of tourist attractions:

> ''Visitor can ***breathe in romance of the past***.''

What does it mean? Please explain it to me.

Comment: Are you sure you have transcribed correctly? Should it be **Visitors** (plural), and maybe a **the** before romance.

Comment: Also, the singular count noun *visitor* would rarely be used without an article or other determiner before it, such as *a visitor* or *the visitor*.

Comment: Not necessarily @djna 'visitor' can be the same as **the** 'visitor'.

Comment: @Sam Harrington I'm intrigued, a bare **Visitor** at the start of a sentence? Do you have a reference to where you have seen this used?

Comment: Surely this has too many articles. I'm certain that the sentence is originally **_Wisitor can breathe in romance of past._**

Answer (score 2):

It's a commonly used play on a word that isn't even mentioned: the word [atmosphere](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/atmosphere) has two main meanings:

> 1.1 The air in any particular place
>   2 The pervading tone or mood of a place

The expression **breathe in the romance of the past** suggests the atmosphere (air) also contains the atmosphere (mood).

Answer (score 1):

> *(A)* visitor can breathe in *the* romance of the past.

is a metaphorical expression meaning that as a visitor you can experience or take-in the environment/surroundings as if you were really there.